# How does the parameter 'a' of the numpy mean function work?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and numpy and I am having trouble to understand the parameter for the mean function.

I defined my data like this.

```
mean = [2, 0.5]
cov = [[0.8, 0.1],[0.1, 0.5]]
np.random.seed(17)
C1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov,50).T
```

Now I want to approximate the mean values. I do it like this:

```
C1.mean(1)
// returns array([ 1.81203223,  0.45002797])
```

I am confused by this solution, since I cant wrap my head around the parameter concept.

Docs for numpy.mean state:

> a : array_like Array containing numbers whose mean is desired. If a is
>   not an array, a conversion is attempted.

For me this sounds like the normal way to call this function would be 
`numpy.mean(C1`) which results in

```
(1.1310301021862881)
```

Similar Using C1 without parameter also results in a single value. I dont know why?

```
 C1.mean()    
 //returns array(1.1310301021862881)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to avoid conceptual confusion I'll change your `mean` variable name:

```
In [794]: mparam = [2, 0.5]
In [795]: cov = [[0.8, 0.1],[0.1, 0.5]]
In [796]: np.random.seed(17)
In [797]: C1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mparam, cov,50).T
In [798]: C1.shape
Out[798]: (2, 50)
```

So your `C1` array is 2d; the 2 coming from the size of `mparam`, the `50` from the 3rd argument to the `normal`.

Look at the `docs` of the `method` version of `mean`:

```
In [799]: C1.mean?
Docstring:
a.mean(axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False)

Returns the average of the array elements along given axis.

Refer to `numpy.mean` for full documentation.

See Also
--------
numpy.mean : equivalent function
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

`C1.mean(1)` calls this with the first argument being `1`; let's do the same with the keyword version:

```
In [800]: C1.mean(axis=1)
Out[800]: array([ 1.81203223,  0.45002797])
```

The function version of `mean` is the same, except the first argument is the array itself:

```
In [801]: np.mean(C1, axis=1)
Out[801]: array([ 1.81203223,  0.45002797])
```

If the distinction between method and function is confusing, you many need to review some Python basics about class definitions.

`C.mean()` leaves `axis=None`, its default.  The docs of `np.mean` offer more details on this `axis` parameter.  If `None` (i.e. not provided), it takes the mean of all 100 values of `C1`, resulting in one value.  With `axis=1` it takes the mean of each row of `C1`, hence 2 values.

A more detailed discussion of the meaning of the `axis` parameter in functions like `mean` and `sum`:
[Sum along axis in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733479/sum-along-axis-in-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2):

There are two different functions involved here:

1. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html
2. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.mean.html

The first is used like `np.mean(C1)`.  The second is used like `C1.mean()` and does the same thing.  But when you say `C1.mean(1)`, that `1` is being used as the `axis` parameter, which gives you a vector instead of a scalar result.