# Numpy max along axis

Tags: numpy

Am I missing something here? I would expect that `np.max` in the following snippet would return `[0, 4]`...

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [0, 4]])

>>> np.max(a, axis=0)
array([1, 4])
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you want the row that contains the maximum value, right?

`max(axis=0)` returns the maximum of [1,0] and [2,4] independently.

`argmax` without axis parameter finds the maximum over the whole array - in flattened form.  To turn that index into row number we have to use `unravel_index`:

```
In [464]: a.argmax()
Out[464]: 3
In [465]: np.unravel_index(3,(2,2))
Out[465]: (1, 1)
In [466]: a[1,:]
Out[466]: array([0, 4])
```

or in one expression:

```
In [467]: a[np.unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)[0], :]
Out[467]: array([0, 4])
```

As you can see from the length of the answer it's not the usual definition of  maximum along/over an axis.

[Sum along axis in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733479/sum-along-axis-in-numpy-array) may give more insight into the meaning of 'along axis'.  The same definitions apply to the `sum`, `mean` and `max` operations.

===================

To pick row with the largest `norm`, first calculate the norm.  `norm` uses the `axis` parameter in the same way.

```
In [537]: np.linalg.norm(a,axis=1)
Out[537]: array([ 2.23606798,  4.        ])
In [538]: np.argmax(_)
Out[538]: 1
In [539]: a[_,:]
Out[539]: array([0, 4])
```

Comment: Ah...I was thinking that max( ) returns the largest row/column (as measured in terms of say, sum-of-squares of the elements). Thanks.

Comment: I added an example of using the `norm` to rank the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([
             [1,2],
             [0,4]
                  ])
np.max(a, axis=0)
```

For a two-dimensional array, we have two axis, axis=0 and axis=1.

axis=0 means going along columns and axis=1 means going along rows.

The **output of the code is an array [1,4]**, which means 1 is the maximum along the 1st column and 4 is the maximum along the 2nd column.

[image: Explaining axis=0 and axis=1]