# NumPy - Format array by max value

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following values:

```
student_list = [521 597 624 100] # Ids of students
grade_list = [[99 73 97 98] [98 71 70 99]] # Grades per student, first array are grades of student #521 for exercise #1 (4 grades)
```

My goal is to return a multidimensional array that for each student, will get the max grade he got in all exercises.

desired output example:

```
[[521 597 624 100] [ 99 73 97 99]]
```

`[521 597 624 100]` - the IDS of the students

`[ 99 73 97 99]` - The maximum grade per exercise, in exc #1 the highest betweeen `98` and `99` is `99`, next is `73`, and so on.

How I can return it using NumPy? I have looked after `argmax()` but not sure how to put it together.

Comment: Seems you need the `axis` keyword, see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41913449/numpy-max-along-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `np.amax`:

```
grade_list = np.array([[99, 73, 97, 98], [98, 71, 70, 49]])

np.amax(grade_list,axis=0)
```

output:

```
array([99, 73, 97, 98])
```