# Numpy indexing logic regarding axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

When we have a `numpy` array, and want to perform an operation along one axis, why is `axis=1` equivalent to working across a **row**, and `axis=0` equivalent to working down a **column**?

As can be seen in the example below, creating a `numpy` array requires specification of the dimensions, via the kwarg `size`, in:

```
np.random.randint: (low, high=None, size=None, dtype='l')
```

This is a tuple, for example(of the forms: `size=(number_of_rows, number_of_columns)`

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 20, (3, 4))

>>> a
array([[16,  7,  4,  7],
       [ 4, 10,  8,  5],
       [ 7,  1, 15,  7]])

>>> np.sum(a, axis=0)
array([27, 18, 27, 19])

>>> np.sum(a, axis=1)
array([34, 27, 30])

>>> a.shape[0]
3

>>> a.shape[1]
4
```

Summing across **rows** is performed by setting the `axis=1`, where I would expect `axis=0`.

Is there a good reason for this? It just confused me every time I used it, until I got simply became accustomed to it. Why does it contradict (in my opinion!) the standard way of indexing arrays, as in the example in the code with the `shape` attribute?

#### update

Here is some more (confusing?) code, showing that `axis=0` works for a 1d array, as one might expect.

```
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])

>>> np.sum(b, axis=0)
15

>>> np.sum(b, axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    np.sum(b, axis=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1814, in sum
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 32, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

I would expect this as the default, given a 1d array can only really be summed in one direction.
Thanks for the input in the comments. I think the answer regarding performance from Stephan is the right one. Is produces this small quirk in numpy that becomes the norm.

Comment: I answered this question a few months back.  I'll have to look it up.  For the moment forget the row v column names.  If `a` is 1d, what does `a.sum(axis=0)` do?  What extension is consistent when working with 2d?  With 3d?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733479/sum-along-axis-in-numpy-array; there the poster is trying understand `axis` in a 3d case.  In some ways that's clearer than the 2d case.  `sum(axis=i)` removes the `ith` dimension, and leaves the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are arguing that the `axis` argument for numpy "reduce" operations, i.e. operations that reduce the number of dimensions - typically by one is operating illogically. Your argument is that given a 2d array the "surviving" dimension is not the one specified. Tellingly, you are using the phrase summing *across*.

Please allow me to demonstrate that this criticism is untenable. The much more consistent concept is summing **along** an axis and specifying not the surviving axis but the one that is **consumed** by the reduce operation.

To see this think 3d or 100d. If you average a stack of images you get one average image, so you are averaging *along* the stacking axis which is consumed in the process. By your logic - you'd specify this process in terms of the surviving axes, x and y - which is clearly misguided, think 100d - where you'd have to enumerate 99 surviving axes to describe a single reduction along a single axis.

If you are comfortable with maths you can also easily convince yourself, that the integration or summation variable is the one that's gone afterwards. Matrix multipliction: The summation dimension is the one that does not feature in the result AB = C -> c_jl = sum_k=1^n a_jk b_kl

Similarly thinking of a shape (M, N) as number-of-rows, number-of-columns works in 2d, but nowhere else. In 3d it would become number-of-x-y-planes, number-of-x-z-planes, number-of-y-z-planes, in 100d number-of-x1-x2-x3-...-x99-hyperplanes, number-of-x0-x2-x3-...-x99-hyperplanes, ... Much better thinking of (M, N) as column-length, row-length.

I could go on like this but if by now you are not convinced then I don't see what could convince you.

Comment: Your point: "Much better thinking of (M, N) as column-length and row-length", along with the link in the comment above from @hpaulj helped me.

Comment: Also, I was not criticising anything about numpy, nor claiming it to be illogical - I was asking for an explanation to something that confused me, as it seemed inconsistent (based on my limited experience).

Comment: @DexterMorgan No problem at all. Maybe I misread your pitch a tiny bit. Sorry about that. Hope my sermon wasn't too preaching ;-)

Comment: I liked your analogy about integration. Perfect! For the first time i think i understand this axis logic on sum like operations.

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing is a common source of confusion in `numpy`.  There is an excellent discussion of this topic in the [numpy docs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numpy/numpy/master/numpy/doc/internals.py).

**The source of confusion:**

> The first thing to understand is
>   that there are two conflicting conventions for indexing 2-dimensional arrays.
>   Matrix notation uses the first index to indicate which row is being selected and
>   the second index to indicate which column is selected. This is opposite the
>   geometrically oriented-convention for images where people generally think the
>   first index represents x position (i.e., column) and the second represents y
>   position (i.e., row). This alone is the source of much confusion;
>   matrix-oriented users and image-oriented users expect two different things with
>   regard to indexing.

**The answer:**

Like so much else in numpy, the answer to the question is because: *performance*:

> So if this is true, why not choose
>   the index order that matches what you most expect? In particular, why not define
>   row-ordered images to use the image convention? (This is sometimes referred
>   to as the Fortran convention vs the C convention, thus the 'C' and 'FORTRAN'
>   order options for array ordering in numpy.) The drawback of doing this is
>   potential performance penalties. It's common to access the data sequentially,
>   either implicitly in array operations or explicitly by looping over rows of an
>   image. When that is done, then the data will be accessed in non-optimal order.

Comment: np.meshgrid` takes an `indexing` paremeter that lets you choose between `ij` and `xy` styles.  Basically it just switches the order of `I,J` tuple that it returns.  But seems to me that confusion is different from that involving the`axis` parameter in functions like `sum`.  As to performance, on a 1000x1000 array, `sum(axis=1)` is 1.4x faster (not a huge difference).