# numpy.all axis parameter misbehavior?

Tags: python, numpy, axis

I have a following array.

```
a = np.array([[0, 5, 0, 5],
              [0, 9, 0, 9]])
>>>a.shape 
Out[72]: (2, 4)

>>>np.all(a,axis=0)
Out[69]: 
array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

>>>np.all(a,axis=1)
Out[70]: 
array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Because axis 0 means the first axis(row-wise) in 2D array,

I expected when `np.all(a,axis=0)` is given, it checks whether all element is True or not, per every row.

But it seems like checking **per column** cause it gives output as 4 elements like `array([False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)`.

What am I misunderstanding about np.all functioning?

Comment: `axis=0` is per col for 2D. The axes start from left as 0,1,2, etc.

Comment: I remember seeing a good duplicate for this, but I can't find it.

Comment: Think of the `axis` argument as the the axis you are collapsing.  When you pass `axis=0`, you are collapsing all of the rows, to one row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733479/sum-along-axis-in-numpy-array - meaning of 'sum along axis' explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`axis=0` means to AND the elements together **along** axis 0, so `a[0, 0]` gets ANDed with `a[1, 0]`, `a[0, 1]` gets ANDed with `a[1, 1]`, etc. The axis specified gets collapsed.

You're probably thinking that it takes `np.all(a[0])`, `np.all(a[1])`, etc., selecting subarrays by indexing along axis 0 and performing `np.all` on each subarray. That's the opposite of how it works; that would collapse every axis but the one specified.

With 2D arrays, there isn't much advantage for one convention over the other, but with 3D and higher, NumPy's chosen convention is much more useful.

Comment: um, it's a bit of late though, but thanks anyway!. I finally understood this.!