# Python: general sum over numpy rows

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I want to sum all the lines of one matrix hence, if I have a `n x 2` matrix, the result should be a `1 x 2` vector with all rows summed. I can do something like that with `np.sum( arg, axis=1 )` but I get an error if I supply a vector as argument. Is there any more general sum function which doesn't throw an error when a vector is supplied? Note: This was never a problem in MATLAB.

Background: I wrote a function which calculates some stuff and sums over all rows of the matrix. Depending on the number of inputs, the matrix has a different number of rows and the number of rows is `>= 1`

Comment: I think it would be better i provided the original matrix.

Comment: You should use axis=0 to sum over rows, not axis=1.

Comment: @Pierre see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52491277/10873281

Comment: @Steradiant, I think you misunderstood the meaning of the arrows in the table you linked. The arrows indicates other what you are summing, so summing over the rows for axis=0. They do not indicate the shape of the result.

Comment: The issue in your case is that for a vector, axis=0 do not correspond to "row" because a 1D array doesn't have any row. But you just need to check your_array.shape just like scandav did in his answer.

Comment: MATLAB does not have 1d arrays.  Everything is 2d.

Comment: How about `np.sum(arr, axis=-1)`.  That works with both a (n,m) producing (m,), and (n,) producing a scalar.  What's ambiguous in your question is whether a `(n,)` shape array should be treated like a `(1,n)` or a `(n,1)`.  Is the `n` dimension the first (0) or last (-1); it's both.  For wayward MATLAB users the concept of a 1d array is confusing; most other programming languages have a basic 1d array or list, with various ways of making it multidimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to numpy.sum [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy-sum), you cannot specify `axis=1` for vectors as you would get a numpy `AxisError` saying `axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`.

A possible workaround could be, for example, writing a dedicated function that checks the size before performing the sum. Please find below a possible implementation:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1, 4],
             [2, 3]])

v = np.array([1, 4])

def sum_over_columns(input_arr):
    if len(input_arr.shape) > 1:
        return input_arr.sum(axis=1)
    return input_arr.sum()

print(sum_over_columns(M))
print(sum_over_columns(v))
```

In a more pythonic way (not necessarily more readable):

```
def oneliner_sum(input_arr):
    return input_arr.sum(axis=(1 if len(input_arr.shape) > 1 else None))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
np.sum(np.atleast_2d(x), axis=1)
```

This will first convert vectors to singleton-dimensional 2D matrices if necessary.